# type "URL" has no type "fileURL" - Not able to pass a String Array as a string

Tags: swift

Getting the error when passing pathArray as a `fileURLWithPath`.

```
func downloadImageForPhoto(_ photo: Photo, completionHandler: @escaping (_ success: Bool, _ errorString: String?) -> Void) {

        taskForGETMethod(photo.photoURL, parameters: nil, parseJSON: false) { (result, error) in
            if error != nil {
                photo.imagePath = "unavailable"
                completionHandler(false, "Unable to download Photo")
            } else {
                if let result = result {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        let fileName = (photo.photoURL as NSString).lastPathComponent
                        let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
                        let pathArray = [path, fileName]
                        let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "\(pathArray)")
                        FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: fileURL.path, contents: result as? Data, attributes: nil)

                        photo.imagePath = fileURL.path
                        completionHandler(true, nil)
                    })
                } else {
                    completionHandler(false, "Unable to download Photo")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot expect to join an array of strings by the `/` separator using String Interpolation.

What you can do is

```
let pathURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
let fileURL = pathURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
```

Nevertheless there is indeed a way to pass an array of components to an URL initializer. Although it's related to `NSURL` it returns an `URL` instance.

```
let fileURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPathComponents: pathArray)!
```

PS: I'd always recommend to use the URL related API to get the `Documents` directory and to create the file.